# parsing values inside () in psutil.sensors_temperatures() in Python in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: python

So I have this JSON string with me

```
`{'nvme': [shwtemp(label='Composite', current=45.85, high=79.85, critical=84.85)], 
'pch_cannonlake': [shwtemp(label='', current=62.0, high=None, critical=None)],
'iwlwifi_1': [shwtemp(label='', current=51.0, high=None, critical=None)],
'coretemp': [shwtemp(label='Package id 0', current=55.0, high=100.0, critical=100.0), 
    shwtemp(label='Core 0', current=55.0, high=100.0, critical=100.0),
    shwtemp(label='Core 1', current=53.0, high=100.0, critical=100.0),
    shwtemp(label='Core 2', current=53.0, high=100.0, critical=100.0),
    shwtemp(label='Core 3', current=51.0, high=100.0, critical=100.0)]}`
```

and I'm using Python to read values from this string. So how can I access shwtemp() and 'label' inside this JSON.

I've already tried `varName['nvme']['shwtemp']` but shows error.

Now I got this 'JSON' from psutil.sensors_temperatures()

What I'm trying to do is to get CPU Temps in python in Ubuntu 20.04. So any improvement could be great...

Comment: That's not a JSON string.

Comment: This is an invalid JSON.

Comment: I see.... I'mma edit it to include more info....

Comment: The functions in `psutils` directly return Python objects; JSON has absolutely nothing to do with this.  Those `shwtemp(...)` objects are *named tuples*, so you'd retrieve that first temperature value as `varName['nvme'][0].current` - a dictionary lookup, followed by a list indexing, followed by an attribute lookup in the named tuple.

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: @jasonharper That makes sense.... Anyways, I got it....

Comment: @furas Yes boss, I'll make sure I do that next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have list with one or more `shwtemp` and you should use index `[0]` to get first element or `for`-loop to work with every element separatelly.

And later you have object `shwtemp` which has field `.current`

```
data = psutil.sensors_temperatures()

print('First:', data['nvme'][0].current)

# or

for item in data['nvme']:
    print(item.current)
```

---

Minimal working example which displays `coretemp` (which has more values so `for`-loop seems useful)

```
import psutil

data = psutil.sensors_temperatures()
print('\n--- type ---')
print(type(data))  # dict
print('--- value ---')
print(data)

core = data['coretemp']
print('\n--- type ---')
print(type(core))  # list
print('--- value ---')
print(core)

item = core[0]
print('\n--- type ---')
print(type(item))  # object shwtemp
print('--- value ---')
print(item)
print('--- fields ---')
print('label   :', item.label)
print('current :', item.current)
print('high    :', item.high)
print('critical:', item.critical)

# -------------------------------------------------

data = psutil.sensors_temperatures()

print('\n--- First ---')
print('First:', data['coretemp'][0].current)

print('\n--- for-loop ---')
for item in data['coretemp']:
    print(item.label, ':', item.current)
```

Result:

```
--- type ---
<class 'dict'>
--- value ---
{'acpitz': [shwtemp(label='', current=57.0, high=102.0, critical=102.0), shwtemp(label='', current=39.0, high=96.0, critical=96.0)], 'radeon': [shwtemp(label='', current=56.0, high=120.0, critical=120.0)], 'coretemp': [shwtemp(label='Core 0', current=58.0, high=95.0, critical=105.0), shwtemp(label='Core 2', current=60.0, high=95.0, critical=105.0)]}

--- type ---
<class 'list'>
--- value ---
[shwtemp(label='Core 0', current=58.0, high=95.0, critical=105.0), shwtemp(label='Core 2', current=60.0, high=95.0, critical=105.0)]

--- type ---
<class 'psutil._common.shwtemp'>
--- value ---
shwtemp(label='Core 0', current=58.0, high=95.0, critical=105.0)
--- fields ---
label   : Core 0
current : 58.0
high    : 95.0
critical: 105.0

--- First ---
First: 58.0

--- for-loop ---
Core 0 : 58.0
Core 2 : 60.0
```

Comment: This works great... You solved my issue... Thanks....!!